# One word for "Wild Wild West" - not the movie!

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'd like to capture the spirit of the phrase "the Wild Wild West" in one word, if possible. For instance *"As I stepped back outside, I was shocked to see everything change to --a scene much like the Wild Wild West---"*.

I would like to capture the feeling of chaos or frenzy, violence or danger, and lawlessness. What would you suggest?

Comment: You mean a lot of people shooting one another, or a lot of horse dung, or olde-fashioned dresses on women, or a cattle stampede, or what?

Comment: Extremely closely related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/22251

Comment: Also tangentially related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/134760 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/41798 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/164561 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/143782 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/62289

Comment: *Wild Wild West* is a television series and a film. Surely you are referring to the *Wild West*, referring to those times and places in American frontier territories where settlement had begun but over which there was no law enforcement or other effective government presence.

Comment: Wild west doesn't seem as wild as Wild, Wild west ... which is double the wild? When I think of just "wild west", I think of cowboys and stuff but not the lawlessness and shoot-outs. 

Thank you for the previous questions/answers but I am looking for a "world of chaos and discord"...something more close to Hell itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bedlam)...

> **bedlam** *- a scene or state of wild uproar and confusion.*
>    *(Archaic, an insane asylum or madhouse.)*

Comment: This is super close to what I have in mond, I don't think it can get closer?

Comment: I am selecting this, but I think the word I was looking for was "pandemonium", or something similar to "bedlam" that would describe a chaotic scenery like Hell

Comment: Googling [define bedlam pandemonium](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+bedlam+pandemonium&oq=define+bedlam+pandemonium&aqs=chrome..69i57.32194305j0j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows that each of those words frequently figures in definitions of the other.

Comment: *[Bedlam](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=bedlam)* derives from the name of a [London hospital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethlem_Royal_Hospital) so thinking of it as capturing “the spirit of the phrase "the Wild Wild West" in one word” is dumbfounding!

Comment: @jwpat7: I assume OP is actually focussed on a *feeling of chaos or frenzy, violence or danger, and lawlessness*, and that the Wild West is just one possible metaphoric reference (which for some reason he *doesn't* want to use, or he wouldn't be asking for an alternative).

Comment: I agree that's the gist of the second paragraph of the question ~ so its two paragraphs are somewhat at odds with each other

Comment: @jwpat7: Yeah - I almost closevoted as Too Broad rather than answering. But OP's comments above do at least suggest I had the right idea about what kind of word he was looking for, even if the question text itself isn't particularly clear on that point.

Answer (score 2):

A word that is sometimes associated with the wild, wild west is **"untamed"** since historically, the far western regions of the continental United States were the last to settle down and become a civilized society.  It took time, people and resources to build up the frontier with cities, citizenry and infrastructure, so initially, it was a combination of intrepid adventurers and even people seeking to live in a place with fewer laws and societal constraints that helped create the reputation of the "wild, wild west".

["The Untamed West"](http://books.google.com/books?id=yCwvyAWpA3MC&dq=untamed%20west&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5PzsU8OWOcedygS6nYGYDg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA) is a book title of three short novels written by the most iconic names in western lore: Zane Gray, Max Brand and Louis L'Amour

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you want is "frontier. Placing it into your example sentence, "As I stepped back outside, I was shocked to see everything change to a *frontier* scene--one much like the Wild Wild West---"

Comment: This was my first thought too, but I'm not sure "frontier" necessarily has the same connotations of chaos, at least not when presented without modifiers.

Comment: I see your point, but it has those connotations for me.

Answer (score 1):

As I stepped back outside, I was shocked to see a world descended into *anarchy.*

*Anarchy* literally means without government, and thus is a good match for the "lawlessness" portion of your request, and additionally has connotations of chaos, violence and danger.

Comment: I think this one fits pretty closely!

Answer (score 0):

Consider *a Dodge City shootout*.  [Dodge City, KS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodge_City) is  “famous in American culture for its history as a wild frontier town of the Old West” [wikipedia].  In the modern age, this image was reinforced by the 1939 film *[Dodge City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodge_City_%281939_film%29)*.  A review of that film at [imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031235/) says it inspired Mel Brook’s ‘Blazing Saddles’; you might also consider the phrase  *a Blazing Saddles shootout* if that better fits your desired tone.